# Можно ли добавить разделитель между элементами OptionsMenu?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!
Задался вопросом, а можно ли добавить горизонтальную или вертикальную линию между элементами `OptionsMenu`? Мне кажется, что нельзя, да и решения я не нашел вообще, однако решил уточнить.
Вот пример как должно быть, т.е. между пунктами меню есть и вертикальные и горизонтальные разделители(они стандартные, на эмуляторе есть), а на устройсве, куда я ставлю прогу, там нет таких, просто отображается текст, без линий. Подскажите как это реализовать принудительно?

[image]

Comment: конечно, кастоми свою разметку...

Comment: а можно пример?

Comment: можно, как и написал @Gorets, делаешь кастомное меню и, как вариант, на background ставишь картинки с нарисованными линиями.

Comment: @Макс покажи на картинке как оно должно выглядеть в итоге, подскажем что-то оптимальное

Comment: добавил картинку, того, как должно быть